# Using Rails as a "Half-API"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im not sure if what I want to do is possible or even makes sense, basically I want to use a rails application that server a API and has a web component as well.

My plan is to have some sensors send POST data (from some Raspberry Pi Zero's) to this rails backend. I want to also be able to GET sensor data in JSON form from the backend api via some sort of nice URL (GET sensor_id/temp or something).

However I also want to be able to have a sort of dashboard that displays values over X timeline for instance.

At that point, does it really make sense using the new rails 5 API addition (`--api` when making a new rails project) or should I actually separate it into 2 separate backends? (Feeding one into the other)

Comment: This is a pretty common pattern, you should be fine having your API and your web view as part of the same rails app. The rails new project builder is just there to give you an easy scaffolding for getting started, and shouldn't dictate anything about the final form of your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  You would define your controller action like this:

```
def index
    @people = Person.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        #do some html specific stuff here
      end
      format.json { render :json => @people.to_json }
    end
  end
```